# Bulk rename without changing the file type

Tags: powershell, windows-explorer

I need to bulk rename files by adding "_Rev-" to the ends of the name. The file extension type of .pdf needs to stay the same. I've tried about 10 different variations to the below strings in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name + "_Rev-"} 
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + "_Rev-" }
```

Instead of changing my file name from `##-##-####.pdf` to `##-##-####_Rev-.pdf` it changes it to `##-##-####.pdf_Rev-`.

I've searched different topics but wasn't quite able to get to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.BaseName` and `.Extension`

```
Get-Childitem *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + "_Rev-" + $_.Extension}
```